# IPTABLES: Drop all non-vpn packets exiting the eth0 access point

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, openvpn

**Project:**
I am building a portable VPN box for each workstation in my office using the *Raspberry Pi 3 B+* and *OpenVPN*, each being outfitted with an LCD screen and buttons so my employees can select the VPN provider, server and network on the fly. A network connection is provided via *wlan0*, routed through *tun0/VPN* and forwarded to *eth0* which acts as a secure access point for work machines. I am using a Raspberry Pi for routing because I really like the idea of network isolation and the ability to modify the device as I see fit.

**Issue:**
IPTABLES is being used to audit the network traffic in order to prevent non-vpn packets from leaving the network, unless it's destination is the VPN server. The rules I am using work great and the workstation is supplied a secure network, however, once OpenVPN is killed, non-vpn packets are still being forwarded to the workstation. Even with the tun0 interface removed via the shutdown of OpenVPN, a working connection remains for the workstation. Packets are dropping just fine on the Pi itself.

I have tried to resolve this by inserting/deleting the *tun0 MASQUERADE* rule via DHCP hooks, DHCPCD hooks (both system & user hooks), and if.down/if.up scripts. The DHCPCD hooks worked fine with *non-tun0* interfaces. I would much prefer to tackle this at the packet level though, as it seems like the most secure route. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Excerpt From Bash Script:**

```sh
# INTERFACES
NIC_WLAN=wlan0
NIC_ETH=eth0
NIC_TUN=tun0

# ISOLATE SERVER URL & WLAN GATEWAY ADDRESS
VPN_SERVER=`cat $vpn_file | grep -m 1 "remote*" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2`
GATEWAY=`route -n | grep $NIC_WLAN | egrep "^0\.0\.0\.0" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2`

# START OPENVPN
openvpn --config $vpn_file --auth-user-pass ./express_vpn/auth.conf &

# FLUSH IPTABLE RULES & USER CHAINS
iptables -F
iptables -X VPN

# IPTABLES POLICY
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# CREATE NEW IPTABLE CHAINS
iptables -N VPN

# TUN0/ETH0 FORWARDING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $NIC_TUN -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $NIC_TUN -o $NIC_ETH -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j RETURN
iptables -A FORWARD -i $NIC_ETH -o $NIC_TUN -j RETURN

# PACKET EXCEPTIONS
iptables -A VPN -o lo -j RETURN
iptables -A VPN -o $NIC_TUN -j RETURN
iptables -A VPN -o $NIC_ETH -j RETURN
iptables -A VPN -d 127.0.0.1 -j RETURN
iptables -A VPN -d $GATEWAY -j RETURN
iptables -A VPN -d $VPN_SERVER -j RETURN

# DROP REMAINING PACKETS
iptables -A VPN -j DROP

# OUTBOUND TRAFFIC RULES
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j VPN
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j VPN
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j VPN

# DNS HANDLER: CLOUDFLARE
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

**iptables -S**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N PIBOX
-N VPN
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j RETURN
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j VPN
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j VPN
-A OUTPUT -p udp -j VPN
-A VPN -o lo -j RETURN
-A VPN -o tun0 -j RETURN
-A VPN -o eth0 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 192.168.0.1/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 185.192.16.18/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 185.192.16.3/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 185.192.16.8/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -d 185.192.16.13/32 -j RETURN
-A VPN -j DROP
```

**iptables -t nat -L**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

---

**UPDATE NOV 16 2019**

> If you want a secure design, invert your logic - start by denying everything and then allow the exceptions you want.

After many hours of fiddling with tables and reading manuals, this suggestion seems to have worked like a charm! Packets are dropping without a hitch on the workstation. Additionally, this method really helped me visualize the routing process during trial and error, though I'm still light years away from you networking virtuosos.

Supplied below are the new Raspi IPTABLES and *tun0* up/down scripts, which I am utilizing via the **up**, **down** and **down-pre** options in OpenVPN.

**Excerpt From Bash Script:**

```sh
# INTERFACES
NIC_WLAN=wlan0
NIC_ETH=eth0
NIC_TUN=tun0

# ISOLATE VPN PORT, WLAN GATEWAY, ETH0 INET
GATEWAY_WLAN=`route -n | grep $NIC_WLAN | egrep "^0\.0\.0\.0" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2`
VPN_PORT=`cat $vpn_file | grep -m 1 "remote*" | cut -d " " -f3`
INET_ETH=`route -n | grep $NIC_ETH | cut -d " " -f1`

# CLEAR IPTABLES
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F

# SET IPTABLES POLICY TO DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# ALLOW LOCAL HOST COMMUNICATION
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW ETH > ETH COMMUNICATION
iptables -A INPUT -s $INET_ETH/24 -d $INET_ETH/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s $INET_ETH/24 -d $INET_ETH/24 -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW OUTBOUND UDP PACKETS VIA VPN PORT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport $VPN_PORT -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW TUN IFACE TRAFFIC
iptables -A INPUT -i $NIC_TUN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $NIC_TUN -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW TUN/ETH FORWARDING
iptables -A FORWARD -i $NIC_TUN -o $NIC_ETH -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $NIC_ETH -o $NIC_TUN -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW ESTABLISHED & RELATED INPUTS
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# LOG & DROP ALL REMAINING PACKETS
if [[ $1 = "log" ]] || [[ $1 = "LOG" ]]; then
    iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
    iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
    iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
fi
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

# DNS HANDLER: CLOUDFLARE
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf

# START OPENVPN
openvpn --config $vpn_file --auth-user-pass ./$vpn_provider/auth.conf &
```

**/etc/openvpn/tun_up**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
NIC_TUN=tun0
NIC_ETH=eth0
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o $NIC_TUN -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i $NIC_ETH -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
```

**/etc/openvpn/tun_down**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
NIC_TUN=tun0
NIC_ETH=eth0
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o $NIC_TUN -j MASQUERADE
iptables -D INPUT -i $NIC_ETH -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
```

**iptables -S**

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -d 255.255.255.255/32 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.220.0/24 -d 192.168.220.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.220.0/24 -d 192.168.220.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT_DROPPED: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

**iptables -t nat -S**

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**DNS leaks** were occurring on the workstation with these rules, with ping requests resolving after OpenVPN was killed, so I executed the following commands to further reinforce the use of the CloudFlare nameserver:

```sh
echo "resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf" > /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i '/dnsmasq_resolv=/d' /etc/resolvconf.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base logic is insecure - your default forward policy is ACCEPT, **and then your  VPN drop policy only matches stuff related to the VPN interface.** and this is your problem..

If you want a secure design, invert your logic - start by denying everything and then allow the exceptions you want.

If you are using NAT you may want to allow established and related traffic as well. Also, you should allow ICMP globally and look at MTU clamping as these will offset some issues induced by VPN overheads.

Comment: Could you clarify your comment regarding **established and related NAT connections**? In context, do you mean something like: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`?